# Vue emmitting component property appears to skip parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been stuck on this for a long time now and I can't find anything remotely similar to this problem online.

Context: Simple restaurant review website.

My application needs to be able to take webcam photos using WebRTC or upload photos from storage. I built a component to do this called `AddImageDialog` that lets the user select either webcam or upload a stored image by storing the image URL in prop on this component and then emitting it. The parent then handles where to place the image.

One part of my program that requires this is the `NewReview` component, that allows 5 photos to be uploaded, all using the same AddImageComponent.

There is a page for users to upload a new restaurant They may also leave a review on this page, so the `Review` component with the `AddImageDialog` is imported onto this page. This page must also allow the user to upload an official photo for the venue, so I have reused my AddImagedDialog on this page.

The problem... When uploading review photos (on the new restaurant page) whenever uploading via webcam, everything works fine but when uploading a stored image, the image seems to be emmitted but skips the `NewReview` parent component and jumps right back to the grandparent - `NewRestaurant`.

## AddImageDialog.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <v-layout row justify-center>
      <v-dialog v-model="thisShowDialog" max-width="550px">
        <v-card height="350px">
          <v-card-title>
            Take a new photo or choose an existing one...
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <div>
              <!-- Add a new photo option -->
              <div class="clickBox left" @click="showCamera = true">
                <v-container fill-height>
                  <v-layout align-center>
                    <v-flex>
                      <v-icon size="40pt" class="enlarge">add_a_photo</v-icon>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-container>
              </div>



              <!-- Add photo from library -->
              <div class="clickBox right" @click="uploadImage">
                <v-container fill-height>
                  <v-flex>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file-input" v-on:change="onFileChange"> 
                    <v-icon size="40pt" class="enlarge">photo_library</v-icon>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-container>
              </div>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-layout>

    <Camera 
      :showCamera.sync="showCamera"
      :photoData.sync="thisPhotoData">
    </Camera>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import Camera from '@/components/Camera'

export default {
  props: ['showDialog', 'photoData'],
  data () {
    return {
      thisShowDialog: false,
      showCamera: false,
      thisPhotoData: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadImage () {
      var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-input') // createElement('input', {type: 'file'})
      fileUpload.click()
    },
    onFileChange (event) {
      let files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files
      if (!files.length) {
        return
      }

      this.createImage(files[0])
      this.thisShowDialog = false

      this.thisShowDialog = false
    },
    createImage (file) {
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = e => {
        alert('reader loaded')
        this.thisPhotoData = e.target.result
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    showDialog () {
      this.thisShowDialog = this.showDialog
    },
    thisShowDialog () {
      this.$emit('update:showDialog', this.thisShowDialog)
    },

    showCamera () {
      // when hiding the camera, leave this component too.
      if (!this.showCamera) {
        this.thisShowDialog = false
      }
    },

    thisPhotoData () {
      alert('emmiting from add image comp')
      this.$emit('update:photoData', this.thisPhotoData)
    }
  },
  components: {
    Camera
  }
}
</script>
```

Sorry to post so much code, but I literally have no idea what's causing this problem.

You will notice I have tried to get both webcam and image uploads to work in the same way by assigning to a `photoData' variable and emitting it whenever it's been changed. I'm confused as to why they behave differently.

## NewReview.vue

(this is the component being skipped by stored imaged uploads)

```
<template>
<!-- LEAVE A REVIEW -->
<v-expansion-panel class="my-4" popout>
    <v-expansion-panel-content expand-icon="mode_edit">
    <div slot="header">Been here before? Leave a review...</div>
    <v-card class="px-3">
        <v-alert :value="isLoggedIn" type="warning">
            You are not logged in. <a href="/login">Log in.</a>
        </v-alert>
        <v-form v-model="validReview">
            <!-- Title -->
            <v-text-field
                name="title"
                label="Review Title"
                v-model="thisReview.title"
                :rules="reviewTitleRules">
            </v-text-field>

            <!-- Body -->
            <v-text-field
            name="body"
            label="Review Body"
            multi-line
            v-model="thisReview.reviewBody"
            :rules="reviewBodyRules">
            </v-text-field>

            <v-card-actions>
                <!-- Submit -->
                <v-btn v-if="canSubmit" :disabled="!validReview" class="primary" @click="submitReview">Submit</v-btn>  
            
                <!-- Select Rating -->
                <star-rating-input
                    class="ratingSelectStyle" 
                    :star-size="25"
                    active-color="#E53935" 
                    v-model="thisReview.reviewRating"
                    :show-rating="false">
                </star-rating-input>

                <v-spacer />

                <!-- Add and View 5 review images -->
                <div v-for="i in 5" :key="i" @click="addImage(i-1)">
                    <review-image 
                        :photoData="reviewPhotos[i-1]"
                        :id="i"
                    ></review-image>
                </div>

                <!-- Add Images Component -->
                <AddImageDialog
                    :showDialog.sync="showCamera"
                    :photoData.sync="photoData"    
                ></AddImageDialog>

            </v-card-actions>
        </v-form>
    </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>    
</template>

<script>
import RestaurantService from '../services/RestaurantService'
import ReviewImage from '@/components/ReviewImage'
import StarRatingInput from 'vue-star-rating'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
import AddImageDialog from '@/components/AddImageDialog'

export default {
  props: ['review', 'restaurantID'],

  data () {
    return {
      showCamera: false,
      photoData: '',
      reviewPhotos: ['', '', '', '', ''],
      currentReviewPhoto: 0,

      thisReview: this.review || {
        title: '',
        reviewBody: '',
        reviewRating: 5,
        user: 'Anon'
      },
      validReview: true,
      reviewTitleRules: [
        s => !!s || 'Title is required',
        s => s.length >= 5 || 'Title must be at least 5 characters'
      ],
      reviewBodyRules: [
        s => !!s || 'Body is required',
        s => s.length >= 10 || 'Body must be at least 10 characters'
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addImage (i) {
      this.currentReviewPhoto = i
      this.showCamera = true

    //   the rest of this is handled by watching for photodata to be changed by the camera component.
    },
    setName () {
      this.thisReview.user = this.$store.state.isLoggedIn ? this.$store.state.user.name : 'Anon'
    },
    submitReview: async function () {
      try {
        await RestaurantService.submitReview(this.restaurantID, this.thisReview).then(res => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            this.$store.dispatch('setNoticeText', 'Review Submitted')
          }
        })
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          //   console.log('404 - Failed to submit')

          this.$store.dispatch('setNoticeText', '404 - Failed to submit review')
        } else {
          this.$store.dispatch('setNoticeText', 'An unexpected problem has occured. [' + err.response.status + ']')
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({isLoaded: 'isLoaded'}),
    canSubmit () {
      if (this.restaurantID) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
    isLoggedIn () {
      if (this.isLoaded && !this.$store.state.isLoggedIn) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    thisReview: {
      handler () {
        this.$emit('update:review', this.thisReview)
      },
      deep: true
    },
    isLoaded () {
      if (this.isLoaded) {
        this.setName()
      }
    },
    photoData () {
      if (this.photoData !== '') {
        this.reviewPhotos[this.currentReviewPhoto] = this.photoData
        this.photoData = ''
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    StarRatingInput,
    ReviewImage,
    AddImageDialog
  },
  mounted () {
    this.setName()
  }
}
</script>
```

This works by defining 5 images for a review and an array of 5 strings, then depending on what image was selected, assigning the emmitted image from `AddImageDialog` to the appropriate array by watching for photo data. As mention, this watcher function will work with the webcam, but is skipped when uploading images.

I'm not even sure if whatever is causing this problem is in this code, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think there is no need to define and watch property 'photoData',you can use two way binding on reviewPhotos[i](of course,you must implement v-model in your component)